# How to replace “\” with “\\” from a string using ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript

Tried:

```
str="test\hello";

str= str.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
```

But it didn't work.
Can someone help me?

Comment: `str` doesn't contain a ``\``. `\h` results in ``h``. Your replacement method is correct though.

Comment: What Felix points out is true. `"test\\hello".replace(/\\/, "\\\\")` works fine